# Friend class keyword not working properly in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class base_A {
public:
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1;
    int sum();
    friend class base_B;
};
class base_B {
public:
    int mul();
};
class derive :public base_A,public base_B{
public:
    void sum_d();
};
int base_A::sum() {
    int s = a + b;
    return s;
}
int base_B::mul() {
    int m = a * b;
    return m;
}
void derive::sum_d() {
    cout << "Sum " << base_A::sum() << "\n";
};
int main()
{
    derive dobj;
    dobj.sum_d();
    dobj.mul();
}
```

Even though I've mentioned base_B class as a friend class of base_A. It couldn't able to access the variables in class base_A.
I'm getting
Error   C2065   'a': undeclared identifier  Public Inheritance
Anyone help me on this as I am new to C++

Comment: "_It couldn't able to access the variables in class base_A_" But in `base_B::mul` you didn't try to access the variables belonging to `base_A`. You tried to access non-exstent variables `a`, and `b`.

Comment: `public` data doesn't require a `friend`. You need to fully specify where you're getting your data from. Composition would be a better fit.

Comment: don't confuse classes and objects. Making a class a friend lets you access an instance members, but without an instance, there are no members you could access

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius : So what should I do to access objects in another class ??

Comment: @user01 As already explained in other comments: you are confusing instances (objects( with a class. Unless you are talking about `static` variables - you aren't talking about access of "a class variables", but rather, about access to a instance variables. For which, you, well, need a class instance. Even then, in your usage of `a * b`, there's no qualifier on neither `a`, nor `b`, stating that they should come from a different scope than `base_B`.

Comment: when I give you the key to my house, you still need to go to my house to take the pizza from my fridge. Having the key does not automatically give you the pizza. (actually not sure if this helps or I am just hungry)

Answer (score 1):

This function definition

```
int base_B::mul() {
    int m = a * b;
    return m;
}
```

is invalid because the class base_b does not have data members a and b.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>

class base_A {
private:
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1;
public:    
    int sum() const;
    friend class base_B;
};

class base_B {
public:
    int mul( const base_A & ) const;
};

class derive :public base_A,public base_B{
public:
    void sum_d() const;
};

int base_A::sum() const {
    int s = a + b;
    return s;
}

int base_B::mul( const base_A &a ) const {
    int m = a.a * a.b;
    return m;
}
void derive::sum_d() const {
    std::cout << "Sum " << base_A::sum() << "\n";
};

int main()
{
    derive dobj;
    dobj.sum_d();
    std::cout << "Mul " << dobj.mul( static_cast<const base_A &>( dobj ) ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Sum 11
Mul 10
```

Comment: :But the purpose of using friend keyword is to access them right ?/

Comment: @user01 Yes, but `base_B` doesn't have a `base_A` object to work with. How should it know which `base_A` instance you want to use? If it had been `int base_B::mul(const base_A& a) { return a.a * a.b; }` or if `base_B` inherited `base_A`. it would have worked.

Comment: @user01 You need to supply an object of the type base_A to data members of which members of the class base_B will have an access.